# Div slips on another div with internet explorer only

Tags: css

In the videos playlist at the bottom, video description (background black) needs to go 20 pixels down. You will understand it better if you view the website with Firefox.

[links not working anymore]

```
#content #videos .playlist { float:left; width:442px; height:292px; margin:10px 0; background:#FFFFFF url(images/bg_videoplaylist.gif) repeat-x; background-position:-1px 0; border:1px solid #083684; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries { position:absolute; width:10000em; height:60px; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries .video { float:left; width:422px; height:60px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; padding:20px; background:transparent url(images/player_entry.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries .playing {  background-position:0px -80px; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries .paused { background-position:-432px -80px; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries .progress { opacity:0.8; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries em { float:right; color:red; font-style:normal; margin:14px; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries .description { float:right; width:442px; height:212px; background:#000 url(http://flowplayer.org/img/player/btn/play_large.png) right bottom no-repeat; }
#content #videos .playlist .entries .description p { color:#FFF; width:422px; height:192px; font-size:12px; font-weight:none; text-decoration:none; padding:10px; position:absolute; }
```

Comment: Looks good on IE8. If anything, you may be forced to use alternative stylesheet to fix this.

Comment: You're screen shot link does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the suggestion above worked. I solved it with `margin-left:-20px`. Hate internet explorer!

Answer (score 0):

IE6/7 has issues with mixing floats and absolute positioning. Try removing the `position:absolute` from `#content #videos .playlist .entries .description p`

Answer (score 0):

Your link is broken, the correct url should be http://pangeaadvisors.org/SS.jpg

- In Firefox 3.5 I see it exactly the
  same as your screenshot of IE (20
  pixels raised).
- In IE6 I see it aligned to the base
  but with 20px on the left
- and IE7 the same as IE6 but with some glitch
  in the scrolling.

In firefox the first 2 items are miss-placed, but the 3rd item in the playlist is displayed correctly. The factor effects this is the length of the title. Longer title display fine, shorter with the 20px gap, the line-height pushes the time-stamp down.

If you add another div inside the "video" wrapping around the title and define a height and width on this with overflow:hidden, it should standardize and stop the issue of some blocks being different heights to others.

With this done you can then use a couple of CSS hacks to write rules for any misbehaving browsers by using

```
position:relative;
top:XXpx
```

A little down-and-dirty but should work just fine. Can't be more specific since I can't actually re-create your problem in my browsers.